# How to pass a meteor user name to a invoking java script as a argument from HTML

Tags: meteor, intuit-partner-platform

Here is the sample code. I am invoking this javascript from HTML with menuProxy and grantUrl as argument, to grant url I want to attach meteor userid as a query parameter. Please advise on how to achieve this.

```js
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
  menuProxy: 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/QuickbooksV3API/bluedot.htm',
  grantUrl: 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/QuickbooksV3API/requesttoken.htm'+'?custId='+ {{currentUser.username}}
});
```

I get following error when I try to run "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" as it is confused meteor handle bar with JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use handlebars syntax in Javascript. However, calling `Meteor.user` in Javascript will give you the same result as `{{currentUser}}` in templates.

```js
grantUrl: 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/QuickbooksV3API/requesttoken.htm?custId='
           + Meteor.user().username
```